# How do I uninstall the System Monitor program?

Tags: installation, software-center

It looks like the Gnome System Monitor programme itself consumes high varying CPU when launched from the system monitor active process list.

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 4):

I just thought I would add a bash option, so open up your terminal and type the following.

Gnome

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-system-monitor
```

Gnome Shell

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell-system-monitor
```

and that's it! plus you get to feel link a Linux geek using the terminal!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can easily uninstall the Gnome System Monitor from the Software Center.

- Open Software Center, type `gnome-system-monitor` in the search box, click on the result and then click on the remove button as shown:

[image]