# How can I update Gnome system monitor?

Tags: gnome, 16.04, system-monitor

I noticed there's a [new version](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-system-monitor/) of Gnome system monitor while my version is **3.18.2**. I tried [to remove](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157469/how-do-i-uninstall-the-system-monitor-program) and reinstall it but I still have the same version. Opening Software Updater doesn't recommend me an update.

Comment: You are using Xenial?

Comment: @andrew.46 yes.

Comment: OK I have successfully installed the newest version and put the details in an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my Xenial system `gnome-system-monitor` is fairly straightforward to build from source. First allow access to source code:

```
Dash > Software & Updates > Ubuntu Software >  Source Code
```

Then allow the system to reload the repositories. Pick up the build dependencies for `gnome-system-monitor` by running the following from within a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-system-monitor
```

Then download, compile and install `gnome-system-monitor` with the following *single command* which can be copied and then pasted into a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall && \
mkdir -v $HOME/Desktop/gnome-system-monitor_build && \
cd $HOME/Desktop/gnome-system-monitor_build && \
wget https://download.gnome.org/sources/gnome-system-monitor/3.20/gnome-system-monitor-3.20.1.tar.xz && \
tar xvf gnome-system-monitor-3.20.1.tar.xz && cd gnome-system-monitor-3.20.1 && \
./configure && make && \
sudo checkinstall --pakdir "$HOME/Desktop/gnome-system-monitor_build" \
     --backup=no --deldoc=yes --pkgname gnome-system-monitor --pkgversion 3.20.1 \
     --fstrans=no --deldesc=yes --delspec=yes --default
```

Log out and then back in (or simply open Dash, close it and then reopen it) and you should then see the following, (a screenshot taken from my own installation on Xenial Xerus):

[image]

Runs nicely on my system and when a new version is released this method can easily be tweaked to install the very latest version :)

Comment: thanks andrew.46 very much works for me :) http://i.imgur.com/EPtCL1t.png

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses tested version of Gnome thats older. If you wish to use latest, install Ubuntu Gnome and then add Gnome PPA but get ready for some issues. I use Arch with Gnome 3.2, so far its been OK but issues crop up from time to time.

Comment: what's the ppa of gnome-system-monitor?

Comment: There is no ppa for Ubuntu Unity, as I said, install Ubuntu Gnome and then install gnome ppa https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging

Comment: this is gnome 3 ppa but i asking for system monitor ppa.

Comment: You can download the 3.20 version for Yakkety from the link given below and install it on Xenial but there is no separate PPA for gnome-system-monitor for Ubuntu. Is there any reason you want the latest one btw? I am on Arch with gnome latest as well as Ubuntu Xenial, I see nothing new added between both versions.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `sudo apt-get install`, followed by its package name? In this case it's `sudo apt-get install gnome-system-monitor`.

Should you have no idea what this is: Open Terminal, copy and paste the following command, press Enter, input your password (which you might not see the asterisks as you type -- just keep typing), press Enter, and answer any prompts that may be on screen.

For Ubuntu, [the latest version of System Monitor is 3.20.1-1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-system-monitor).

Comment: please read the question before answering :) .

Comment: Okay, sorry for that. How about `sudo apt-get update`?